# jupyterlab-myst: how to install or enable myst extension?

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-lab, myst

I am using [jupyterlab-myst](https://pypi.org/project/jupyterlab-myst/), a really cool extension.

The [MyST documentation on Topography](https://myst-parser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/syntax/typography.html) mentions several extensions such as "attrs_block", "attrs_inline", "tasklist", "deflist", and "fieldlist".  I believe those are MyST extensions, not JupyterLab extensions.

I copied the markdown text from the examples in [Topography](https://myst-parser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/syntax/typography.html) into my jupyter notebook and got jupyterlab-myst to render them.  The examples do not work in the notebook like they do in the MyST documentation page, except for the [Definition List example](https://myst-parser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/syntax/typography.html#definition-lists-and-glossaries).

The MyST documentation page refers to a configuration file called "conf.py".  I believe that applies to the Jupyter Book tool, not JupyterLab.  How can I install / activate / enable / configure / whatever to get MyST extensions to work in JupyterLab?

Although this question is tagged with "myst", I am asking about jupyterlab-myst, not myst.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jupyterlab-myst` developer here. You'll get better support opening issues in our GitHub repo in future!

`jupyterlab-myst` is separate from the Sphinx `myst-parser` project that feeds into `jupyter-book`. The common element is the MyST syntax, but even that has extensions that aren't supported everywhere just yet; we're standardising things and building out our JS stack as I write this reply!

Steve's reply refers to our Sphinx stack, but you're asking about our JS stack (via our JupyterLab extension). Right now, we don't have any customisation options; those are planned, but we're initially just getting things off the ground.

Comment: Thanks Angus for clearing up the difference between jupyterlab-myst and Sphinx.

Answer (score 0):

From [jupyterlab-myst Usage](https://pypi.org/project/jupyterlab-myst/):

> By default, the MyST renderer becomes the default notebook renderer.

Thus I assume you need to enable all those MyST extensions. See the documentation. For example, for [`attrs_block`](https://myst-parser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/syntax/optional.html#block-attributes):

> By adding `"attrs_block"` to `myst_enable_extensions` (in the sphinx `conf.py` configuration file), you can enable parsing of block attributes before certain block syntaxes.

That would look like the following.

```
myst_enable_extensions = [
    "attrs_block",
    "attrs_inline",
    "tasklist",
    "deflist",
    "fieldlist",
]
```

Comment: Where do I put this?  What is the pathname to the config file?  I am not familiar with the config files in JupyterLab.

Comment: In `conf.py`. This is the Sphinx configuration file.